# Can wget be used to pull specific data from a webpage?

Tags: command-line, wget

Can the wget command be used to pull specific data from a web site, for instance; "cubs score" from www.sportscore.com?  If so, what would be recommended syntax?

Answer (score 2):

`wget` (or `curl`, for that matter) can't do that, but then the usual practice is to fetch the page and extract the relevant parts using another tool preferably one that understands HTML. For example, to fetch Premier League table data from BBC, I do:

```
curl http://www.bbc.com/sport/football/tables -Ls | 
  pup '.gel-long-primer tr td:nth-child(3), .gel-long-primer tr td:nth-child(10), .gel-long-primer tr td:nth-child(11) text{}'
```

(which gets me the team names, goal difference and points, which I later process using `awk`, etc. to create a Cann table.)

Inspect the source of the page to see if the HTML element with the score you're interested has an identifying characteristic, like an `id` or `name` attribute, or is related to one which you can otherwise filter, then use `pup`, etc. to get that element from the data downloaded by `wget` or `curl`. The site you mentioned doesn't open for me, so I can't help with that.